# C# reading from Azure SQL function extremely slow

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database

This seems very likely to be some sort of an Azure SQL issue, but I can't figure out what's going on. I have some code that reads data from a SQL function like this:

```
using SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
myConnection.Open();

using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[function] (@param)", myConnection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", param));

using SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

I'm using the function here so I don't need to have a rather elaborate SQL query written among C# code. When I run the function via SSMS, it runs in a few seconds. This was also the case when run from C# last week. However, for some reason this morning the function was really slow initially even when run via SSMS, taking a bit over 2 minutes to run. It has normalized in SSMS since this morning but it is timing out when run via C#. The Azure SQL database is serverless min 0.5 to max 4 vCore. What's going on and how to fix this issue?

Edit: I may have found a solution. The problem has to do with parameter sniffing in SQL Server. I got the function to work by adding a local parameter that is assigned the function parameter, so the function parameter will not actually be used in any queries. I'll have to see if this keeps working and I'll then mark this as answer if it doesn't break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a local parameter that is assigned the function parameter at the beginning and using it in the function's queries solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you said if you are facing  parameter sniffing in SQL Server. One query, two plans depending on parameters, it's parameter sniffing. As this [post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/02/inline-table-valued-functions-parameter-snorting/) said

```sql
DECLARE @Id INT = 22656
SELECT *
FROM dbo.BC_ITVF(@Id) AS bi
GO

DECLARE @Id INT = 4338144
SELECT *
FROM dbo.BC_ITVF(@Id) AS bi
GO
```

Then our plans look like this:
[image]

We can use a RECOMPILE hint to go back to the original plans with literals.